# best arima model in R

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I'm new to R. I'm trying to fit an ARIMA model to a large time series. The best model found with auto.arima is ARIMA(0,0,5). The residuals plotted with tsdisplay are looking like below. Can someone tell me how to improve the model?
[image]

The time series represents hourly spot electricity price collected for several years. The original time series looks like below:
[image]

and the log-return first differenced time series:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert for time series analysis an just getting familiar with it. However, you should first try to provide more information about your data. How does the data look like? Can you give a plot? What is your time series about? The big outlier around lag 24 looks suspicious. It is quite difficult to give an advice for an appropriate ARIMA model with only a plot of the residuals of a certain fitted model. Additionally, you should not choose your model only on grounds of auto.arima(). Imagine you have an ARIMA(0,0,1) model, which has an AIC only very slightly higher than the one of the ARIMA(0,0,5). Due to reasons of parsimonity (using a model as simple as possible) I would still recommend the MA(1).

Try auto.arima(x,trace=TRUE), which shows you all considered ARIMA models, a model with a higher AIC might have residuals with a WN behavior.

But again, try to give more information on your problem.